# Visio data model diagram to db

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008, visio

I have created my db data model diagram using Visio. Is there a way to generate the DB schema from the Visio?

Appreciate your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this requires the, "Visio Enterprise Architect" edition.